# Dtrace fbt provider on windows not working

Tags: windows, dtrace

I'm running `Dtrace` on windows and when trying to execute this command-line script

```
dtrace -n "fbt:nt:*Timer*:entry { @k[probefunc] = count(); } tick-5s { trunc(@k, 10);printa(@k); exit(0); }"
```

as given in official microsoft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/dtrace#installing-dtrace-under-windows, the output dumped by `dtrace` is :-

```
dtrace: description 'fbt:nt:*Timer*:entry ' matched 391 probes

CPU     ID                    FUNCTION:NAME

  0  45932                         :tick-5s
```

Why is the output empty ?

I have followed all the steps given in documentation in the VM

Comment: Are you sure the probes that `fbt:nt:*Timer*:entry` matches are actually being hit? You can test this with `dtrace -n 'fbt:nt:*Timer*:entry'`.

Comment: Yes probes are not getting hit , any reason why is that so ?

Comment: Dtrace fbt provider not working for VM